# Varnish on cPanel server req.http.X-Forwarded-For not working

Tags: apache, cpanel, varnish

I have installed Varnish (uses 4.0 vcl format) and i did like here: http://wiki.mikejung.biz/How_To_Forward_IP_Header_Varnish_Apache

```
if (req.restarts == 0) {
    if (req.http.X-Forwarded-For) {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
    } else {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
    }
}
```

in vcl file and

```
<IfModule mod_remoteip.c>
   RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
   RemoteIPInternalProxy 127.0.0.1
</IfModule>
```

in cPanel include editor. But i am still see only server IP in logs. This is very important because csf and mod_security cant block briteforce attacks on server. Varnish itself running ok.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Varnish 4 doesn't require any changes in vcl config file
2. Include mod_remoteip module in Apache configuration
3. Add to `/usr/local/apache/conf/mod_remoteip.conf`

   RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For

   RemoteIPInternalProxy 127.0.0.1 ...
4. Replace in lines including logformat: `'%h'` with `'%a'` in `/var/cpanel/conf/apache/main`
  5.

/scripts/rebuildhttpdconf

/sbin/service httpd graceful